# echo stdin, unless empty, in which case cat a file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04, pipe, cat

The pipeline `fstdraw in.fst | dot -Tpng | convert - -rotate 90 out.png` converts a file in a certain binary format into a PNG image.

Unfortunately, in some cases `fstdraw` emits zero bytes.  (A bug in its package, [OpenFst](http://www.openfst.org).)  Then `dot` too emits zero bytes instead of a PNG, whereupon `convert` fails to create `out.png`.  That missing file then breaks later commands.

At the first pipe symbol, how can one insert something that means *echo my input, but if my input is empty, instead output the file dummy.txt*, so `out.png` is always created?

(One could write a script, but surely some shell builtin or [standard tool](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/echo-msg.html) does this already.)

Something like `fstdraw in.fst | cat_maybe dummy.txt | dot ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explicit answer

The package `moreutils` provides `ifne` tool. Normally it runs the given command if and only if the standard input is *not* empty. It has, however, a *reverse operation* mode:

> ```
> -n
> ```
>
> Reverse operation. Run the command if the standard input is empty.
>
> Note that if the standard input is not empty, it is passed through `ifne` in this case.

So the solution is:

```
fstdraw in.fst | ifne -n cat dummy.txt | dot -Tpng | convert - -rotate 90 out.png
```

---

### Alternative approach

This was posted originally as a comment. The point is to detect when `convert` fails and act accordingly. The method doesn't answer the explicit question, yet it may solve your specific problem. I'm posting it here for educational purpose.

```
fstdraw in.fst | dot -Tpng | convert - -rotate 90 out.png || cp dummy.png out.png
```