# How to make long pipeline work with echos

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting

I wrote the following `for` loop as part of a larger script that takes text files as arguments, applying several transformations to them:

```
for i; do
echo "Filtering out lines with empty columns...";
awk -F: '$1!="" && $2!=""' "$i" > "${i%.txt}_noempties.txt";
echo "Removing all spaces in first column...";
awk -F: '{gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1 FS $2}' "${i%.txt}_noempties.txt" > "${i%.txt}_nospaces.txt"; # assumes two columns delimited by :
echo "Filtering out lines that don't contain "@" or ":"..."; 
grep -aE ":|@" "${i%.txt}_nospaces.txt" > "${i%.txt}_sanitised.txt"; 
echo "Removing control characters...";
tr -d '\000-\011\013-\037' < "${i%.txt}_sanitised.txt" > "${i%.txt}_noctrls.txt"; # Removes all control characters apart from (Linux) newline
echo "Filtering out very short and long lines...";
awk 'length >=7 && length <=150' "${i%.txt}_noctrls.txt" > "${i%.txt}_lengths.txt";
echo "Sorting and removing duplicate lines...";
LC_ALL=C sort -u "${i%.txt}_lengths.txt" > "${i%.txt}_final.txt";
done;
```

It works but seems very inefficient, needing to wait for the output of the previous command to use it as input for the next one. I'd like to stop using intermediate files entirely and convert the whole thing to a pipe, but when I do that with something like this:

```
for i; do
echo "Filtering out lines with empty columns..." |
awk -F: '$1!="" && $2!=""' "$i" |
echo "Removing all spaces in first column..." |
awk -F: '{gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1 FS $2}' | # assumes two columns delimited by :
echo "Filtering out lines that don't contain "@" or ":"..." |
grep -aE ":|@" |
echo "Removing control characters..." |
tr -d '\000-\011\013-\037' | # Removes all control characters apart from (Linux) newline
echo "Filtering out very short and long lines..." |
awk 'length >=7 && length <=150' |
echo "Sorting and removing duplicate lines..." |
LC_ALL=C sort -u > "${i%.txt}_final.txt";
done;
```

...the script exits immediately. It doesn't show any syntax errors via `bash -n` but pasting it into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) gives errors about piping into `echo` not being allowed.

The same also happens with this:

```
for i; do
echo "Filtering out lines with empty columns..." &&
awk -F: '$1!="" && $2!=""' "$i" |
echo "Removing all spaces in first column..." &&
awk -F: '{gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1 FS $2}' | # assumes two columns delimited by :
echo "Filtering out lines that don't contain "@" or ":"..." && 
grep -aE ":|@" |
echo "Removing control characters..." &&
tr -d '\000-\011\013-\037' | # Removes all control characters apart from (Linux) newline
echo "Filtering out very short and long lines..." &&
awk 'length >=7 && length <=150' |
echo "Sorting and removing duplicate lines..." &&
LC_ALL=C sort -u > "${i%.txt}_final.txt";
done;
```

Is it possible to convert this code into one long pipe while retaining the `echo`s, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

#### Analysis

There is no point in retaining simple `echo`s. Pieces of a pipeline run simultaneously, not in sequence, so even if you manage to make each piece report the beginning of its task to the terminal with `echo` (this can be done), all the echos will report just after the pipe starts and they may not keep the order. Depending on how and how much they print, their output may even get interleaved. Example:

```
{ echo "starting date" >&2; date; } | { echo "starting wc" >&2; wc -l; }
```

Run this line few times. You will find the `echo`s can print in any order. Invoking `echo "Doing everything..."` just before the pipe will give you the same information in a cleaner way.

Still there are cases where tools started simultaneously actually work in sequence. Consider this artificial example (that uses `cat` uselessly, but it's just an example):

```
cat some_file | sort | uniq
```

If `some_file` is [small enough](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/108618) then `sort` may get it in one chunk when `cat` exits. For the same reason `uniq` may get data when `sort` exits. In this case the tools do their respective jobs in sequence, there is no concurrency.

If `some_file` is large, `sort` will start reading, accumulating (and maybe preprocessing) data before `cat` exits. These two tools will work in parallel for some time. When `cat` does its job, it exits and only then `sort` can generate output and pass it to `uniq`. This means `uniq` must sit there and wait, unable to read anything, until `cat` exits.

Conclusion: despite they start at about the same time, in no case `cat` and `uniq` can actually *work* concurrently.

With this observation in mind we may want to generate a message when a tool in a pipeline starts reading data. This makes sense. As a proof of concept I built a script that can do this.

---

#### Script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "-X" ]; then
   marker=1
   fd="$2"
   shift 2
else
   unset marker
   exec {fd}>&1
fi

if [ "$1" = "-m" ]; then
   message="$2"
   shift 2
else
   message="$1 ($$)"
fi

if [ "$marker" ] || [ -t 0 ]; then
   >&2 printf -- '+ %s\n' "$message"
   ( >&"$fd" "$@" )
   status="$?"
   >&2 printf -- '- %s: done [%s]\n' "$message" "$status"
else
   ifne -n "$0" -X "$fd" -m "$message" "$@" | ifne "$0" -X "$fd" -m "$message" "$@"
fi
```

It uses [`ifne`](https://superuser.com/a/1218219/432690) (from `moreutils` package in Debian). The code must be an executable script (I mean don't try to make it a shell function) because it calls itself via `ifne` (and `ifne` cannot run a function).

From now on I assume the script is somewhere in `$PATH` and its name is `report`.

---

#### Usage

Basic usage:

```
$ report echo foo | report wc -l
+ echo (17956)
- echo (17956): done [0]
+ wc (17957)
1
- wc (17957): done [0]
```

This means `echo` worked and exited with exit status `0`. Then `wc` worked and exited with exit status `0`. Numbers in parentheses are PIDs of respective `report` processes (note: not of `echo` nor `wc`); they are meant to distinguish multiple instances of the same tool (if multiple instances occur in the pipe).

More advanced example where actual concurrency can be observed:

```
$ report seq 1 100000 | report grep 9 | report sort -R | report head -n 50 | report grep 00 | report wc -l
+ seq (20602)
+ grep (20603)
+ sort (20604)
- seq (20602): done [0]
- grep (20603): done [0]
+ head (20605)
- head (20605): done [0]
- sort (20604): done [141]
+ grep (20606)
- grep (20606): done [1]
+ wc (20607)
0
- wc (20607): done [0]
```

(The exit status from `grep (20606)` is `1` because by chance this `grep` found no matches; `wc -l` confirms this, it prints `0`. If you run the pipeline few times, it may happen there will be matches. The randomness comes from `sort -R`.)

Observations:

- `seq`, the first `grep` and `sort` actually work concurrently. Generate less data (e.g. `40000` or `4000` instead of `100000`) and you will be able to observe more sequential behavior.
- `head` starts processing data after `sort` (obviously, since it reads from `sort`) but it terminates before `sort`. Then `sort` exits with `141` [because it gets `SIGPIPE`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580119/108618). This is expected, this is how piping works.

`report` accepts custom messages. Let's pimp our pipeline then:

```
$ report -m 'generating data' seq 1 100000 |
  report -m  filtering        grep 9       |
  report -m  sorting          sort -R      |
  report -m  reducing         head -n 50   |
  report -m 'finding 00s'     grep 00      |
  report -m  counting         wc -l
+ generating data
+ filtering
+ sorting
- generating data: done [0]
- filtering: done [0]
+ reducing
- reducing: done [0]
- sorting: done [141]
+ finding 00s
- finding 00s: done [0]
+ counting
1
- counting: done [0]
```

`-m message` is the only option. (Well, there is `-X` but it's for internal use only.)

---

#### Rough explanation

The script (ab)uses `ifne`. This tool runs something iff its stdin is not empty; or it (`ifne -n`) runs something iff its stdin is empty. To know if its stdin is empty or not it must wait for some data or EOF. This makes it useful in our case: `… | report foo` uses `ifne` to delay running `foo` until there is data or EOF. Note it really delays `foo`, so in some (rather exotic?) circumstances it may behave not exactly like `… | foo`.

An exception is when the stdin is a terminal (detected with `[ -t 0 ]`). Run `report cat` in an interactive shell and you will see it does not wait for data, it reports right away the `cat` is working. I decided this is a reasonable approach.

The script runs the desired command, whether stdin is empty or not; for this I needed `ifne` and `ifne -n`. The hard part was to pass the stdin possibly via both variants and to the desired command eventually, while the output of the command should not get to `ifne`. An additional file descriptor makes this possible. It turned out the code is more elegant when `report` calls itself (via `ifne`) instead of invoking `bash -c 'some obscure code that handles the redirection' …` via `ifne`.

---

#### Notes:

- Messages are printed to stderr. Messages from different `report` processes [may interleave](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476089/108618) but if they are not too long then they really shouldn't. Frankly I don't know how long is "too long", I expect "reasonably short" to be "not too long". :) Anyway the problem should be marginal if any.
- Use a trap `trap ':' INT TERM` just after the shebang to make `report` immune to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and plain `kill`. The idea is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> terminates the inner command and `report` still reports this. The trap uses `':'`, not `''`, because the latter would make the script *and* the spawned command ignore the specified signals, while the former only affects the script. Personally I prefer `report` without the trap.
- `report` can run

  - an external executable,
  - a shell function exported from Bash
  - or a Bash builtin. In case of a builtin remember the builtin cannot affect your current shell because the code of `report` runs in a separate shell. Additionally `report` deliberately runs `"$@"` in yet another shell (a subshell), so a builtin cannot affect `report` itself either.
- Aliases will work if you use [this trick](https://superuser.com/a/712377/432690): `alias report='report '`; they will work not because `report` will suddenly understand them but because the shell that invokes `report` will expand them first.
- To run a pipeline (or anything that requires a shell, e.g. a `for` loop) inside a single `report` you need to explicitly invoke an additional shell. Inside the shell you can run more `report`s. Try this example:

  ```
  report seq 1 100000 |
  report -m preprocessing sh -c 'report grep 9  | report sort -R | report head -n 50' |
  report -m    processing sh -c 'report grep 00 | report wc -l'
  ```